# How to get the aggregate at last row count

Tags: pandas

df[df.index.str.contains("Mall/")]

My data frame is below

```
gender  FEMALE  MALE    OTHER
Resp            
['College,Mall/movies'] 1   0   0
['College,Mall/movies'] 0   1   0
['College,Mall/movies,Restaurants'] 0   1   0
['College,Mall/movies'] 0   1   0
['College,Restaurants,Mall/movies'] 0   1   0
```

final_df.columns
`Index(['FEMALE', 'MALE', 'OTHER'], dtype='object', name='gender')`

I need to get the aggregate at last row saying count(Female),count(Male),count(Others) going to Mall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need `sum` all columns to new row:

```
df1 = df[df.index.str.contains("Mall/")]
df1.loc['count_Mall'] = df1.sum()
```